# Is this the correct way of using mclapply?

Tags: r, apply, tapply, mapply

I am attempting to use the **mclapply** function for the very first time, I have two specific questions, one to verify if I am using the mclapply the right way and second with the errors I get. I wrote an Rscript to perform column wise operations using the lapply function on my data file. Since my file has a lot of columns I was hoping to use the mclapply function to process columns in parallel. The following is my code snippet. Would really appreciate help and opinion to make this program better.

```
inputFile=args[1]
start=as.numeric(args[3])
end=as.numeric(args[2])


 ttestoutput.function=function(x,add_argument){
   ......
  }



df<-fread(inputFile,header=T,data.table=FALSE,sep=",")
print("Input file loaded")
col.ind=df[,c(start:end)]
cores_present=detectCores()
additional=c(df$Status,df$Age,df$Sex)
final.output = t(mclapply(col.ind, 2, ttestoutput.function,additional,     
mc.cores=cores_present))

**The errors that I see:**

 Warning message:
 In mclapply(col.ind, 2, ttestoutput.function, additional, mc.cores =    
 cores_present  :
 all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code


 "1",Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Comment: I would recommend to create a minimum example (see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides from that it seems (when looking at the arguments) you mixed up `mclapply` and `apply`. While `mclapply`is the parallel version of `lapply`, `mapply` is used to operate on data frames row or column wise. My advice: go with `lapply` first (on a small example), if you get your desired results, switch to `mclapply`.

Comment: To add to @mariodeng comment, the second argument of `mclapply` is the function. No need for an index like in `apply`. I also find using `mclapply` with one core makes it much easier to diagnose the errors, you can always switch it back once you have fixed your problem.